# If $1\le l\le p\le m$, then show that $r_{lp}(r_{pl}(A))=A$ (Show that Row Switching operation can be inverted)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

First I want to introduce the notation I use:

So,  for the Type I operation in  wich we switch $l^{th}$ and $p^{th}$ rows, I denote it by $r_{lp}(A)$

So, if  $1\le l\le p\le m$, then show that $r_{lp}(r_{pl}(A))=A$

Dem:

Let $A\in M_{(m,n)}(\mathbb{F})$ and $A_1=r_{lp}(A)$, defined as:
$$
R_{i}(A_1) =
\begin{cases}
R_{i}(A),  & \text{if $i\ne l,p$} \\[2ex]
R_{p}(A), & \text{if $i=l$} \\[2ex]
R_{l}(A), & \text{if $i=p$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, let $A_2=r_{lp}(r_{pl}(A))$ or well, $A_2=r_{pl}(A_{1})$, defined as:

$$
R_{i}(A_2) =
\begin{cases}
R_{i}(A_1),  & \text{if $i\ne l,p$} \\[2ex]
R_{p}(A_1), & \text{if $i=p$} \\[2ex]
R_{l}(A_1), & \text{if $i=l$}
\end{cases}
$$

So, we want to prove that $A_2=A=[\alpha_{ij}]$

For $i\ne l,p$ we have see that $R_i(A_2)=R_i(A_1)=R_i(A)$ wich we can interpret as $[
\alpha_{i1}\dots\alpha_{in}]$ for the $i^{th}$ row,

now for $i=l$, we have $R_l(A_2)=R_l(A_1)=R_l(A)$

Until here I seemed to lost the line of reasoning. The next should begin with the condition $l\le p$? Is the first part of the demonstration well defined?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it seems like the next case you want to check is the $i=p$ case.

Alternatively, you can view each row in $A$ as element of a set $X$ with size $m$, and switching two rows is the same as a 2-cycle (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation) for more details) in $X$. By properties of the permutation group $S_X$, all 2-cycles have order 2; that is, applying a 2-cycle twice in a row is the same as doing nothing. This becomes more obvious in your case when you realize that $r_{lp} = r_{pl}$ (that is, they are the same operation).

Comment: I see. Sorry, I have another question. Does the condition $1\le l,p\le m$ must be satisfied by every resulting matrix after applying the operations $r_{lp}(A)$ and $r_{pl}(A_1)$? Whit this I mean that if I got to 'reformulate' what is $l$ and $p$ so that for if for example, $R_l(A)= [0 1], R_p(A)=[1 0]$, and after $r_{lp}$, $R_p(A_1)=[0 1], R_p(A_1)=[1 0]$? Let me know if I made myself clear

Comment: I'm not understanding why $l$ or $p$ would change. Don't you fix them before solving the question? Otherwise, what's the point?